# Removing dualboot

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, ssd

I had Windows 7 installed on my hdd. After adding an 240gb SSD for games/work I added another one for my new windows installation.
So I made a dualboot with my old windows 7 on the HDD and the new Windows 7 on the SSD. I have now removed the old windows 7  on the HDD and wanted to change my boot device to the Windows 7 on the SSD.
But after changing the boot device it won't boot and displays a message 'No bootable device', changing it back to the hdd and it will launch the windows on the SSD

Answer (score 0):

As i read your problem i think the bootloader is only installed on your HDD and not your SSD.

You can try to use the [Automated repair from Neosmart](https://neosmart.net/wiki/easyre/recovery/automated-repair/) (please read the guide permitted on the website before trying), then select the SSD. It will make an bootloader on your SSD. After that try to boot the SSD without the HDD connected.